# ssh PrintLastLog prints actual login

Tags: login, sshd, last

I connect with my server via ssh and always it shows the last log: `Last login: Sat Mar 19 14:05:17 2016 from...` but that login is my actual login. What's the utility of this info? It should print the previous connection.

---

Gentoo 64 bits
Openssh v7.2

Comment: No. It does print the previous login on all of my machines. What is your system, what is your `openssh` version on server?

Answer (score 0):

I've seen this issue when two types of "Last Login:" response were generated.  This is becuase I had pam_lastlog configured as well as the SSH having the default PrintLastLog enabled.